# Принцип действия декоратора Property по шагам в Python

Tags: python

друзья!
Насколько я понял, синтаксис декоратора property внутри класса:

```py
@property
def somefunc(self)
    .
    .
```

эквивалентен:

```py
def somefunc(self)
    .
    .  
somefunc = property(somefunc)
```

Это так? Если да, то непонятно, почему не эквиваленты следующие конструкции внутри класса. Эта:

```py
    @property
    def radius(self):
        return self.__radius

    @radius.setter
    def radius(self, radius):
        self.__radius = radius
```

и эта:

```py
    @property
    def radius(self):
        return self.__radius

    def radius(self, radius):
        self.__radius = radius
    radius = radius.setter(radius)
```

Вторая конструкция не работает. Понятно, вроде почему. К моменту парсинга строчки:

```py
radius = radius.setter(radius)
```

radius - уже не объект propery, а функция.
Тогда непонятно, почему работает первый фрагмент кода???
Который постоянно приводится в примерах в разных учебниках и статьях

Comment: Потому что во втором случае второй `def radius` перезатирает пропертю функцией, и никакого `radius.setter` уже не существует. Поместите вторую функцию в любую другую переменную (например `def radius_setter_func` или лямбду или вообще вынесите за пределы класса) и пишите `radius = radius.setter(radius_setter_func)` и всё будет работать

Comment: Первый фрагмент работает, потому что второй `def radius` не добавляется к содержимому класса до тех пор, пока он не пройдёт через декоратор, а во втором фрагменте идёт попытка применения декоратора уже после того, как функция добавилась к содержимому класса (и тем самым стёрла пропертю).

Comment: Получается конструкция @decorator уже не просто синтаксический сахар, а нечто больше...?

Comment: И в чем суть прохождения через декоратор тогда? Как эту конструкцию  @radius.setter  разложить на составляющие

Comment: Никак, потому что в python отсутствует синтаксис создания функции-выражения без её помещения в какую-либо переменную. Создать эквивалентное декоратору поведение получится только с лямбдами, но внутри лямбд нельзя написать присваивание, так что это бесполезно

Comment: Забавно, тогда почему везде говорится, о синтаксическом сахаре, что на самом деле не так...

Comment: Для простоты объяснения, видимо. Проперти — довольно специфический случай, а во многих других местах применения декораторов оба варианта будут фактически эквивалентны

Comment: Дело не в проперти. Походу, при совпадении имен декоратора и имени оборачиваемой функции, ее имя не учитывается при использовании синтаксиса с @. Странно, что почти нигде об этом не говорится.

Comment: Учитывается. Если написать например [вот так](https://pastebin.com/yVEucRyR), то в классе появится два разных проперти `radius` и `radius2`, которые будут управлять одним и тем же значением, причём через первое проперти значение можно только читать, а через второе — читать и писать. Если вместо этого написать одинаковое имя (как в коде в вашем вопросе), то первое проперти просто заменяется вторым проперти и остаётся одно-единственное проперти, которое можно читать и писать.

Comment: Например, в таком коде https://pastebin.com/Fe1tyAre 
мы не можем заменить @myfunc на myfunc = myfunc(myfunc), написав это после функции. Но что происходит, когда парсер встречает @myfunc? Предположу, что он берет функцию определенную выше myfunc, а в качестве аргумента определенную ниже, не, выполняя ее код определения def, то есть берет просто адрес. Ведь def name():.... тоже определенный код, в отличие от объявлений  функций в других языков типа си